# Finding example for $ G\left(x\right)=\intop_{a}^{x}g\left(t\right)dt $ that is differntiable but $ G'\neq g $

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Find exmaple for an integrable function $ g $ in a segment $ [a,b] $ such that $ G\left(x\right)=\intop_{a}^{x}g\left(t\right)dt $ is differntiable function, but $ G'\neq g $.

For this I have 2 ideas. I'd like to hear if my ideas is correct.

The first one:

let $ g $ be the constant function $ g=0 $ over the segment $ [0,1] $.

Then $ g $ is integrable, and because $ g $ is continious we know that

$ G\left(x\right)=\intop_{a}^{x}g\left(t\right)dt $  is differentiable and $ G'(x)=g(x) $ for any x in the segment.

Now change $ g $ in some inner point in $ [a,b] $, and name the new function $ h $. then for any $ x $ the integral $ \intop_{a}^{x}g\left(t\right)dt $ hasent change, so $ G\left(x\right)=\intop_{a}^{x}g\left(t\right)dt=\intop_{a}^{x}h\left(t\right)dt $

Thus, $ G $ is still differntiable, and $ G'=g\neq h $.

Is this example correct?

Here's another one:

Consider $ g\left(x\right) $ = Thomae function over the segment $ [0,1] $. Then $ g $ is integrable, and $ G\left(x\right)=\intop_{a}^{x}g\left(t\right)dt=0 $ for any $ x $ in the segment. Thus, $ G $ is differntiable and $ G'(x)=0 $ but ofcourse Thomae function isnt the zero function.

I'd like to hear some of your opinions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are right (twice).

Comment: Both examples are correct.